# If i have two closed and disjoint sets A and B in a set X c $R^{m}$, are there any open and disjoint sets in X that contain A and B?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, covering-spaces

I have a set *$X$ $c$ $R^{m}$* and a pair of two closed and disjoint sets in X, called A and B. What i am trying to found at least a pair of sets Y and Z that are open and disjoint in a set *X c $R^{m}$* that include A and B, respectively.

For A, i tried using a cover made of all the balls with center in a point of A and an arbitrary ratio intersected with X - A, but if i do the same for B, how could i know if those two covers are disjoint?

Comment: A nice property of metrisable spaces such as $\Bbb R^n$ is that they have a countable basis. You can use that for your proof and that way 'disjoin' adjacent open sets.

Comment: $$Y=\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid d(x,A)<d(x,B)\}\qquad Z=\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid d(x,A)>d(x,B)\}$$

Comment: Did, your answer was right. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Did's comment. There was an error in my previous solution so I deleted it.